# Recyclerview data gets overridden after scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Here is the partial code from my adapter:

```
    public void add(Information info){
        data.add(info);
        notifyItemInserted(data.size()-1);
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Information current = data.get(position);

        holder.to.setText(current.getTo());
        holder.from.setText(current.getFrom());
        holder.distance.setText(current.getDistance());
    }
```

code for add a row button:

```
mAdapter.add(dataToAdd); 
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1, 0);
```

whenever i add data to my recyclerview, it adds fine, but when i scroll the the entered row starts to override all other rows , please help

EDIT:
The app that i use this on is already published so i really need to fix this.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dijkstra.tqrapps.com.dijkstra

I added alot of numbers to the listview but they start overriding with the latest row

**Update 2:**

```
public class Information {
    private String from,to,distance;

    public Information(){

    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any problems in the code snippet. What do you mean by "overriding"?

Comment: also added my code for add row button

Comment: Still hard to say what may be causing such effect... What happens if you comment out the programmatic scroll lines? Or does it happen even when you scroll manually?

Comment: yeah i even commented out that code and it still happens on manual

Comment: Could you also add the code for your "Information" object model

Comment: yes just added it on Update 2

Comment: Check your `Adapter` implementation.  Are you reporting that items have stable IDs?  If so, are you properly reporting unique IDs (the default implementation of `getItemId()` returns `NO_ID`.

Comment: i think ill just change it to regular listview because i can't fix it, i don't have a getItemId in my adapter